# Error while compiling uuid-ossp packages on postgresql11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

whenever i am trying to compile the uuid-ossp packege i am getting error.

I have tried to install packages in REDHAt os rpm -qa | grep lib64ossp
lib64ossp-uuid16-1.6.2-10.x86_64

```
$:/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/contrib/uuid-ossp>make
make -C ../../src/backend generated-headers
make[1]: Entering directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend'
make -C catalog distprep generated-header-symlinks
make[2]: Entering directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend/catalog'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `distprep'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `generated-header-symlinks'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend/catalog'
make -C utils distprep generated-header-symlinks
make[2]: Entering directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend/utils'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `distprep'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `generated-header-symlinks'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend/utils'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/backend'
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -O2 -fPIC -I../../contrib/pgcrypto -I. -I. -I../../src/include  -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o uuid-ossp.o uuid-ossp.c
uuid-ossp.c:37:2: error: #error "please use configure's --with-uuid switch to select a UUID library"
 #error "please use configure's --with-uuid switch to select a UUID library"
  ^
uuid-ossp.c: In function âuuid_generate_internalâ:
uuid-ossp.c:282:5: error: unknown type name âuuid_tâ
     uuid_t  uu;
     ^
uuid-ossp.c:283:23: error: âuuid_s_okâ undeclared (first use in this function)
     uint32_t status = uuid_s_ok;
                       ^
```

Comment: If you compiled PostgreSQL yourself, then follow the advice: "please use configure's --with-uuid switch to select a UUID library".  If you installed it through a package manager, then use that package manager to install uuid-ossp

Comment: @jjanes can you provide me an example please

Answer (score 0):

If you are not building a contrib module with the source tree it is part of, you have to set `USE_PGXS`:

```
PATH=/path/to/postgres/binaries:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1
```

The path must contain the `pg_config` executable.

To be sure it works, use the contrib source from the same major version as the installed PostgreSQL.

Comment: error $>PATH=/optware/postgres/postgresql-11.2/src/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -O2 -fPIC -I/optware/postgres/11.2/db/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../contrib/pgcrypto -I. -I./ -I/optware/postgres/11.2/db/include/server -I/optware/postgres/11.2/db/include/internal  -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o uuid-ossp.o uuid-ossp.c
uuid-ossp.c:37:2: error: #error "please use configure's --with-uuid switch to select a UUID library

Comment: The link which you have provided is not there now can you revert back with link also  I am getting below error while compiling postgres binary

Comment: checking for uuid_export in -lossp-uuid... no
checking for uuid_export in -luuid... no
configure: error: library 'ossp-uuid' or 'uuid' is required for OSSP UUID

Comment: Then install the package. `yum install libuuid-devel` or similar (depends on the distribution). The link was https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/installation.html.